# The type of namespace name '...' does not exist in the namespace '...' | dotnet restore doesn't help | .NET C# Azure

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-active-directory, dotnet-httpclient, nuget-package-restore

I opened a C# based Microsoft Azure open sourced application:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/blockchain/tree/master/blockchain-workbench/rest-api-samples/dotnet

When opening it in Visual Studio 2017 I get a lot of errors:

[image: Errors]

I've read that it is possible that some packages are referenced but we need to restore it. 
When typing donent restore I get a success message:

Restore completed in 43.1 ms for C:\Users\path\blockchain\blockchain-workbench\rest-api-samples\dotnet\Workbench.Client.csproj.

But still nothing changes and the errors stay.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is your vs 2017 up to date ? Can you check the extension "Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools". More info on prerequisites [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs). Also sometimes a simple restart of visual studio helps...

Comment: Eventually I just downloaded all the packages manually and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error, you just need to download all the required packages.

[image]